# Referring to newly added worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I want to refer to newly added sheets. They are added by a loop.

They are named `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3` etc. I also have a variable `n` which equals to 1 when a `Sheet1` is created, equals to 2 when a `Sheet2` is created, equals to 3 when a `Sheet3` is created, and so on.

My code looks like the following:

```
For i = 2 To 1000

If Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" And Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, "A").Value <> "TOTAL" Then

Worksheets("Template").Cells(1, "C").Value = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, "B").Value
Worksheets("Template").Cells(2, "C").Value = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, "C").Value
Worksheets("Template").Cells(3, "C").Value = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, "A").Value
Worksheets("Template").Cells(5, "D").Value = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, "D").Value
Worksheets("Template").Cells(5, "E").Value = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, "E").Value

Sheets.Add

n = 0
n = n + 1

Worksheets("Template").Cells.Copy

Worksheets("Sheet & n").Range("A1").Paste 'Problem is in this line

Worksheets("Sheet" & n).Activate ' And in this line

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
```

I have a problem with the lines marked with comments.
My question is how to refer to a `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc by using the `n` variable?

Please be patient with me, as I am quite new to VBA. If my question is vague or hard to understand please let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything within quotes `""` will be considered as string.

Change `"Sheet & n"` to `"Sheet" & n`

Also you should avoid the use of `.Activate`. [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

And one more thing :P

You don't need to `Activate` a sheet to paste to it. You can do it in one line. For Example.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy _
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also save a reference to the worksheet when you create it, so you don't have to guess the name. Replace your line `Sheets.Add` with the first two of my lines:

```
Dim oSheet As Worksheet

Set oSheet = Sheets.Add

'***** Do what you need with the sheet
oSheet.Range("A1").Paste
Debug.Print oSheet.Name

'***** Clear the reference when you're done
Set oSheet = Nothing
```

Comment: + 1 I was editing my post with this info but then saw your answer :D

Comment: call me a lazy bum! :D